# MobileFirst unable to load html page

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

When creating an app in MobileFirst ,the html page is not loaded .
The port number in the error message is shown as -1 .
IDE is Eclipse Mars

I followed steps available on this link :https://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-mobile-hybrid-app-using-ibm-worklight-part-1/

On Clicking Finish ,in the wizard ,pops up the error message ,with the index.html opened in the background

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Servers view (press cmd+3 and type "servers")
2. Open the "development server" entry
3. Double-click on "server configuration"
4. Click on "HTTP Endpoint"

Verify that the port value is set to 10080, the default port for MobileFirst Platform in the dev environment.

It'll be good if you'll also edit your question and provide the steps you've followed to get to this situation.

Might be good to also try and restart to start clean in your workstation.

Comment: I am pretty new to MobileFirst ,can you direct me where to check weather port is 10080 .

Comment: Updated the answer. If the port is defined, then try restarting.

Comment: Tried Configuring and restarting ,but the same error message :I wonder where does it pickup -1

Answer (score 0):

`<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="10080" httpsPort="10443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"> <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/> </httpEndpoint>`
1) double click on the server tab 2) and click on the server configuration server.xml file 3) you can find the following line of code ,need to edit the port number as mentioned above